# transfer data in header using PHP with POST method without form

Tags: php, arrays, http, http-headers, http-post

Hi can anyone help me to resolve my problem? I am trying to use template toolkit concept in php and I have written the code but there are some problem to displaying data on the page with echo.

My code is

```
class Template{
    private $path;

    public function __construct($template){
        if($template){$this->path = __ROOT."/crm/".$template."/";}
        else{
            $this->path = __ROOT."/crm/";
        }
    }

    public function process($url,$post_data)
    {
        $url = $this->path.$url;
        $result = $this->processTemplate($url, $post_data);

        if ($result['status'] == 'ok'){
            return $result['content'];
        }
        else {
            return $result['error'];
        }
    }

    function processTemplate($url, $data, $referer=''){

        $data = http_build_query($data);

        $url = parse_url($url);
        if ($url['scheme'] != 'http') {
            die('Error: Only HTTP request are supported !');
        }

        $host = $url['host'];
        $path = $url['path'];
        $fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr,500);
        if ($fp){
            fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n");

            if ($referer != '')
                fputs($fp, "Referer: $referer\r\n");

            fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Content-length: ". strlen($data) ."\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
            fputs($fp, $data);

            $result = '';
            while(!feof($fp)) {
                $result .= fgets($fp, 100000);
            }
        }
        else {
            return array(
                'status' => 'err',
                'error' => "$errstr ($errno)"
            );
        }
        fclose($fp);
        $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
        $header = isset($result[0]) ? $result[0] : '';
        $content = isset($result[1]) ? $result[1] : '';
        return array(
            'status' => 'ok',
            'header' => $header,
            'content' => $content
        );
    }
}
```

and got the data on the passed template but there is a unexpected text is also include at the first of all.
 screenshot:
[result data while trying to get the data using $_POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkRMw.png)

I am processing this template as :

```
$template = new Template("");
    $result='';

    if(isset($input['action'])){
        $result = $template->process('includes/html/header.php',$input);
        echo $result;
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: without a form you would have to use ajax in javascript to do a post

Comment: I need to call a page with post data. like PERL Template Toolkit.

Comment: I have fixed it. now its working fine..

Thank you for reply on this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem like this:

```
   <?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Author: Ajay Kumar
    # Comment: Please make a copy of this code before editing
    # Reply At: If you are facing any problem, please reply at ajaykiet2@gmail.com

    Example: 
    $template = new Template();
    echo $template->process("about-us.php",$data_to_post);
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    require_once('config.php');

    class Template {
        public $ch,$path;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->path = $GLOBALS['siteURL'];
        }

        public function process($url, $data){
        $data = http_build_query($data);
            $URL = $this->path.$url;
            $this->ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 );
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            $response = curl_exec($this->ch);
            $error    = curl_error($this->ch);
            $errno    = curl_errno($this->ch);

            if (is_resource($this->ch)) {
                curl_close($this->ch);
            }
            if (0 !== $errno) {
                throw new RuntimeException($error, $errno);
            }
            return $response;
        }
    } 

    ?>
```